# CoSign API: How to sign a docx using webservice and java

Tags: digital-signature, cosign-api

I want to sign a Word docx file in the CoSign system. I want the signed file to be the Word document; I don't want it converted to be a PDF.
I am using Java. I am using a test program, below, but it isn't working.

```
import com.arx.sapiws.dss._1.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import oasis.names.tc.dss._1_0.core.schema.DocumentType.Base64Data;
import oasis.names.tc.dss._1_0.core.schema.*;
import oasis.names.tc.dss._1_0.core.schema.RequestBaseType.OptionalInputs;
import oasis.names.tc.dss._1_0.core.schema.ResponseBaseType.OptionalOutputs;
import oasis.names.tc.dss._1_0.core.schema.ResponseBaseType.OptionalOutputs.DocumentWithSignature;
import oasis.names.tc.saml._1_0.assertion.NameIdentifierType;


public class CosignWord {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //read file name, signer name, signer password from command line
        if (args.length < 3) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java CosignHelloWorld <pdf-file> <signer-name> <signer-password>");
            return;
        }

        String FileName = args[0];
        String SignerName = args[1];        //cosign user
        String SignerPassword = args[2];    //cosign user password

        System.out.println("Trying to sign '" +FileName+ "' by '"+SignerName+ "' with password '"+SignerPassword+ "' ...");
        if (!checkFile(FileName)) {
            System.out.println("Cannot find '"+FileName+"' or it is read/write protected. Aborting.");
            return;
        }

        //set document properties
        Base64Data corePDFBytes = new Base64Data();
        byte[] fileBytes = getPDFBytes(FileName);
        corePDFBytes.setValue(fileBytes);
        corePDFBytes.setMimeType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
        DocumentType myDoc = new DocumentType();
        myDoc.setBase64Data(corePDFBytes);

        // set signer - USERNAME/DOMAIN
        NameIdentifierType cosignUserProps = new NameIdentifierType();
        cosignUserProps.setValue(SignerName);    //User Name, try "John Miller"
        cosignUserProps.setNameQualifier(" ");      //Domain (relevant for Active Directory environment only)

        // set signer - PASSWORD
        CoSignAuthDataType cosignPassword = new CoSignAuthDataType();
        cosignPassword.setLogonPassword(SignerPassword);    //User Password, try "12345678"

        // set signer - USERNAME+PASSWORD
        RequestBaseType.OptionalInputs.ClaimedIdentity cosignUser = new RequestBaseType.OptionalInputs.ClaimedIdentity();
        cosignUser.setName(cosignUserProps);
        cosignUser.setSupportingInfo(cosignPassword);

     /*   //set signature field settings
        SAPISigFieldSettingsType sigFieldSettings = new SAPISigFieldSettingsType();
        sigFieldSettings.setName("SigField");
        sigFieldSettings.setInvisible(Boolean.TRUE);   //visible
        sigFieldSettings.setX(366);
        sigFieldSettings.setY(705);
        sigFieldSettings.setWidth(182);
        sigFieldSettings.setHeight(58);
        sigFieldSettings.setDependencyMode(DependencyModeEnum.INDEPENDENT);
        sigFieldSettings.setSignatureType(SignatureTypeEnum.DIGITAL);
        sigFieldSettings.setEmptyFieldLabel("");
        sigFieldSettings.setPage(1);*/

        //initiate request components
        RequestBaseType.InputDocuments inputs = new RequestBaseType.InputDocuments();
        inputs.getDocumentHashOrOtherOrDocument().add(myDoc);       

        RequestBaseType.OptionalInputs optInputs = new RequestBaseType.OptionalInputs();
        optInputs.setSignatureType("http://arx.com/SAPIWS/DSS/1.0/signature-field-sign");
        optInputs.setClaimedIdentity(cosignUser);
//        optInputs.setSAPISigFieldSettings(sigFieldSettings);
        optInputs.setSignatureFieldName("Signer 1");
        //optInputs.setReturnPDFTailOnly(Boolean.TRUE);

        //initiate connection to COSign SAPI service
        DSS service = new DSS();
        DSSSoap port = service.getDSSSoap12();

        //doing verify
        VerifyRequest verifyRequest = new VerifyRequest();
        verifyRequest.setInputDocuments(inputs);
        verifyRequest.setRequestID("DummyRequestId");
        OptionalInputs optVerifyInputs = new RequestBaseType.OptionalInputs();
        optVerifyInputs.setSignatureType("http://arx.com/SAPIWS/DSS/1.0/signature-field-verify");
        verifyRequest.setOptionalInputs(optVerifyInputs);
        DssVerifyResult resp = port.dssVerify(verifyRequest);


        //initiate request
        SignRequest request = new SignRequest();
        request.setOptionalInputs(optInputs);
        request.setInputDocuments(inputs);
        request.setRequestID("DummyRequestId");

        //make the call
        DssSignResult result = port.dssSign(request);

        //CHECK RESULT:
        ResponseBaseType.Result rc = result.getResult();
        String errmsg = "" + rc.getResultMajor();
        if (errmsg.compareTo("urn:oasis:names:tc:dss:1.0:resultmajor:Success") != 0) {
            System.out.println("Cannot sign '"+FileName+"' got: "+rc.getResultMessage().getValue());
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Trying to append signature to '" +FileName+ "' ('"+SignerName+ "') ...");

        // IF OK Get the signature:


        OptionalOutputs optOutputs = result.getOptionalOutputs();
        DocumentWithSignature doc = optOutputs.getDocumentWithSignature();
        Base64Data signedDocB64 = doc.getDocument().getBase64Data();
//        DssSignResult.SignatureObject sig = result.getSignatureObject();
//        DssSignResult.SignatureObject.Base64Signature B64Sig = sig.getBase64Signature();

        try
        {
            FileOutputStream FH = new FileOutputStream("signed_"+FileName);
            FH.write(signedDocB64.getValue());
            FH.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error writing to PDF file: " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Signature of '" +SignerName+ "' appended to '"+FileName+ "'.");
    }

    private static byte[] getPDFBytes(String FileName) {
        byte[] pdf;
        // READ THE FILE INTO BUFFER
        try
        {
            File F = new File(FileName);

            if (!F.canRead())
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (!F.canWrite())
            {
                return null;
            }

            pdf = new byte[(int) F.length()];
            FileInputStream FH = new FileInputStream(F);
            FH.read(pdf, 0, (int) F.length());
            FH.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return pdf;
    }    

    private static boolean checkFile(String fileName) 
    {
        try
        {
            File F = new File(fileName);

            if (!F.canRead())
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (!F.canWrite())
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Java example for [CoSign SAPI](http://www.arx.com/digital-signatures/developers). It does the following:

- Signs a pdf file with an ad hoc signature placement in the file
- Verifies the signatures in a file
- Signs a Word docx file that already has a pre-existing signature field
- Sign a PDF file that has a pre-existing signature field
- User management example: lists all of a user's digital certificates

Example:

```
import com.arx.sapiws.dss._1.*;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.util.List;

import oasis.names.tc.dss._1_0.core.schema.DocumentType.Base64Data;
import oasis.names.tc.dss._1_0.core.schema.*;
import oasis.names.tc.saml._1_0.assertion.*;

public class CosignHelloWorld {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //read file name, signer name, signer password from command line
        if (args.length < 3) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java CosignHelloWorld <pdf-file> <signer-name> <signer-password>");
            return;
        }

        String FileName = args[0];
        String SignerName = args[1];        //cosign user
        String SignerPassword = args[2];    //cosign user password
        String FieldNameToSign = args[3];
        String Reason = args[4];

        if (!checkFile(FileName)) {
            System.out.println("Cannot find '"+FileName+"' or it is read/write protected. Aborting.");
            return;
        }


        // Sign DOCX document
        SignDOCXExistField(FileName, FieldNameToSign, SignerName, SignerPassword);

        // Sign PDF document
        SignPDF(FileName, SignerName, SignerPassword);

        // Sign an existing field in a PDF document
        SignPDFExistField(FileName, FieldNameToSign, Reason, SignerName, SignerPassword);

        // Verify all fields in a PDF document
        List<SAPIFieldsInfo> fieldsInfo = VerifyFile(FileName, "application/pdf");
        for (SAPIFieldsInfo fieldInfo : fieldsInfo)
        {
            String status = null;
            if (!fieldInfo.getSignedFieldInfo().isIsSigned())
                status = "Not Signed";
            else
                status = fieldInfo.getFieldStatus().getSignatureStatus() == 0 ? "Valid" : "Invalid";

            System.out.println(fieldInfo.getSigFieldSettings().getName() + " : " + status);
        }

        // Get all user's certificates
        List<byte[]> certs = ListUserCerts(SignerName, " ", SignerPassword);
        for (byte[] certBytes : certs)
        {
            ByteArrayInputStream cert_value = new ByteArrayInputStream(certBytes);
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate X509Cert = (java.security.cert.X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(cert_value);

            System.out.println("Issuer: " + X509Cert.getIssuerDN().getName());
        }
    }

    private static byte[] getPDFBytes(String FileName) {
        byte[] pdf;
        // READ THE FILE INTO BUFFER
        try
        {
            File F = new File(FileName);

            if (!F.canRead())
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (!F.canWrite())
            {
                return null;
            }

            pdf = new byte[(int) F.length()];
            FileInputStream FH = new FileInputStream(F);
            FH.read(pdf, 0, (int) F.length());
            FH.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return pdf;
    }    

    private static boolean checkFile(String fileName) 
    {
        try
        {
            File F = new File(fileName);

            if (!F.canRead())
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (!F.canWrite())
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static void SignPDF(String FileName, String SignerName, String SignerPassword)
    {
        System.out.println("Trying to sign '" +FileName+ "' by '"+SignerName+ "' with password '"+SignerPassword+ "' ...");

        byte[] fileBytes = getPDFBytes(FileName);
        Base64Data corePDFBytes = new Base64Data();
        corePDFBytes.setValue(fileBytes);
        corePDFBytes.setMimeType("application/pdf");
        DocumentType myDoc = new DocumentType();
        myDoc.setBase64Data(corePDFBytes);

        // set signer - USERNAME/DOMAIN
        NameIdentifierType cosignUserProps = new NameIdentifierType();
        cosignUserProps.setValue(SignerName);    //User Name, try "John Miller"
        cosignUserProps.setNameQualifier(" ");      //Domain (relevant for Active Directory environment only)

        // set signer - PASSWORD
        CoSignAuthDataType cosignPassword = new CoSignAuthDataType();
        cosignPassword.setLogonPassword(SignerPassword);    //User Password, try "12345678"

        // set signer - USERNAME+PASSWORD
        RequestBaseType.OptionalInputs.ClaimedIdentity cosignUser = new RequestBaseType.OptionalInputs.ClaimedIdentity();
        cosignUser.setName(cosignUserProps);
        cosignUser.setSupportingInfo(cosignPassword);

        //set signature field settings
        SAPISigFieldSettingsType sigFieldSettings = new SAPISigFieldSettingsType();
        sigFieldSettings.setName("SigField");
        sigFieldSettings.setInvisible(Boolean.FALSE);   //visible
        sigFieldSettings.setX(366);
        sigFieldSettings.setY(705);
        sigFieldSettings.setWidth(182);
        sigFieldSettings.setHeight(58);
        sigFieldSettings.setDependencyMode(DependencyModeEnum.INDEPENDENT);
        sigFieldSettings.setSignatureType(SignatureTypeEnum.DIGITAL);
        sigFieldSettings.setEmptyFieldLabel("");
        sigFieldSettings.setPage(1);

        //initiate request components
        RequestBaseType.InputDocuments inputs = new RequestBaseType.InputDocuments();
        inputs.getDocumentHashOrOtherOrDocument().add(myDoc);       

        RequestBaseType.OptionalInputs optInputs = new RequestBaseType.OptionalInputs();
        optInputs.setSignatureType("http://arx.com/SAPIWS/DSS/1.0/signature-field-create-sign");
        optInputs.setClaimedIdentity(cosignUser);
        optInputs.setSAPISigFieldSettings(sigFieldSettings);
        optInputs.setReturnPDFTailOnly(Boolean.TRUE);

        //initiate connection to COSign SAPI service
        DSS service = new DSS();
        DSSSoap port = service.getDSSSoap12();

        //initiate request
        SignRequest request = new SignRequest();
        request.setOptionalInputs(optInputs);
        request.setInputDocuments(inputs);
        request.setRequestID("DummyRequestId");

        //make the call
        DssSignResult result = port.dssSign(request);

        //CHECK RESULT:
        ResponseBaseType.Result rc = result.getResult();
        String errmsg = "" + rc.getResultMajor();
        if (errmsg.compareTo("urn:oasis:names:tc:dss:1.0:resultmajor:Success") != 0) {
            System.out.println("Cannot sign '"+FileName+"' got: "+rc.getResultMessage().getValue());
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Trying to append signature to '" +FileName+ "' ('"+SignerName+ "') ...");

        // IF OK Get the signature:
        DssSignResult.SignatureObject sig = result.getSignatureObject();
        DssSignResult.SignatureObject.Base64Signature B64Sig = sig.getBase64Signature();

        try
        {
            FileOutputStream FH = new FileOutputStream(FileName, true);
            FH.write(B64Sig.getValue());
            FH.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error writing to PDF file: " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Signature of '" +SignerName+ "' appended to '"+FileName+ "'.");
    }

    /**
     * Verifies a PDF, Word or Tiff file. The file is passed in as a byte array. 
     *   @param FileBytes       The file as byte array. 
     *   @param FileType        The type of the file as defined in ARX SAPI WS spec. Can accept the following values: application/pdf, application/msword, image/tiff
     *   @return                The SAPIFieldsInfo structure that contains the details about all of the signatures present in the file.
     */
    static public List<SAPIFieldsInfo> VerifyFile(String FileName, String FileType) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Validating '" + FileName + "'");

        DssVerifyResult result;
        try {
            byte[] fileBytes = getPDFBytes(FileName);

            DSS service = new DSS();
            DSSSoap port = service.getDSSSoap12();

            RequestBaseType.InputDocuments inputDocs = new RequestBaseType.InputDocuments();
            RequestBaseType.OptionalInputs optionalParams = new RequestBaseType.OptionalInputs();

            // SET SIGNATURE TYPE (verify)
            optionalParams.setSignatureType("http://arx.com/SAPIWS/DSS/1.0/signature-field-verify");

            // SET FLAGS
            optionalParams.setFlags(Long.valueOf(0));

            Base64Data corePDFBytes = new Base64Data();
            corePDFBytes.setValue(fileBytes);
            corePDFBytes.setMimeType(FileType);
            DocumentType myDoc = new DocumentType();
            myDoc.setBase64Data(corePDFBytes);
            inputDocs.getDocumentHashOrOtherOrDocument().add(myDoc);

            // ALL DONE, MAKE A CALL:
            VerifyRequest request = new VerifyRequest();
            request.setOptionalInputs(optionalParams);
            request.setInputDocuments(inputDocs);
            request.setRequestID("DummyRequestId");

            //make the call
            result = port.dssVerify(request);

            // CHECK RESULT:
            ResponseBaseType.Result rc = result.getResult();

            String errmsg = "" + rc.getResultMajor();
            if (errmsg.compareTo("urn:oasis:names:tc:dss:1.0:resultmajor:Success") != 0) {
                throw new Exception(rc.getResultMessage().getValue());
            }

            ResponseBaseType.OptionalOutputs outputs = result.getOptionalOutputs();
            List<SAPIFieldsInfo> fieldInfos = outputs.getSAPIFieldsInfo();
            if (fieldInfos == null) {
                throw new Exception("File is not signed");
            }

            return fieldInfos;
        }
        catch (java.rmi.RemoteException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    private static void SignPDFExistField(String FileName, String FieldNameToSign, String Reason, String SignerName, String SignerPassword)
    {
        System.out.println("Trying to sign '" +FileName+ "' by '"+SignerName+ "' with password '"+SignerPassword+ "' ...");

        byte[] fileBytes = getPDFBytes(FileName);
        Base64Data corePDFBytes = new Base64Data();
        corePDFBytes.setValue(fileBytes);
        corePDFBytes.setMimeType("application/pdf");
        DocumentType myDoc = new DocumentType();
        myDoc.setBase64Data(corePDFBytes);

        // set signer - USERNAME/DOMAIN
        NameIdentifierType cosignUserProps = new NameIdentifierType();
        cosignUserProps.setValue(SignerName);    //User Name, try "John Miller"
        cosignUserProps.setNameQualifier(" ");      //Domain (relevant for Active Directory environment only)

        // set signer - PASSWORD
        CoSignAuthDataType cosignPassword = new CoSignAuthDataType();
        cosignPassword.setLogonPassword(SignerPassword);    //User Password, try "12345678"

        // set signer - USERNAME+PASSWORD
        RequestBaseType.OptionalInputs.ClaimedIdentity cosignUser = new RequestBaseType.OptionalInputs.ClaimedIdentity();
        cosignUser.setName(cosignUserProps);
        cosignUser.setSupportingInfo(cosignPassword);

        //initiate request components
        RequestBaseType.InputDocuments inputs = new RequestBaseType.InputDocuments();
        inputs.getDocumentHashOrOtherOrDocument().add(myDoc);       

        RequestBaseType.OptionalInputs optInputs = new RequestBaseType.OptionalInputs();
        optInputs.setSignatureType("http://arx.com/SAPIWS/DSS/1.0/signature-field-sign");
        optInputs.setClaimedIdentity(cosignUser);
        optInputs.setSignatureFieldName(FieldNameToSign);
        optInputs.setReturnPDFTailOnly(Boolean.TRUE);

        // SET THE REASON
        if (Reason.compareTo("") != 0) {
            ArrayOfConfValueType confValArray = new ArrayOfConfValueType();
            ConfValueType confVal = new ConfValueType();
            confVal.setConfValueID(ConfIDEnum.REASON);
            confVal.setStringValue(Reason);
            confValArray.getConfValue().add(confVal);
            optInputs.setConfigurationValues(confValArray);
        }

        //initiate connection to COSign SAPI service
        DSS service = new DSS();
        DSSSoap port = service.getDSSSoap12();

        //initiate request
        SignRequest request = new SignRequest();
        request.setOptionalInputs(optInputs);
        request.setInputDocuments(inputs);
        request.setRequestID("DummyRequestId");

        //make the call
        DssSignResult result = port.dssSign(request);

        //CHECK RESULT:
        ResponseBaseType.Result rc = result.getResult();
        String errmsg = "" + rc.getResultMajor();
        if (errmsg.compareTo("urn:oasis:names:tc:dss:1.0:resultmajor:Success") != 0) {
            System.out.println("Cannot sign '"+FileName+"' got: "+rc.getResultMessage().getValue());
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Trying to append signature to '" +FileName+ "' ('"+SignerName+ "') ...");

        // IF OK Get the signature:
        DssSignResult.SignatureObject sig = result.getSignatureObject();
        DssSignResult.SignatureObject.Base64Signature B64Sig = sig.getBase64Signature();

        try
        {
            FileOutputStream FH = new FileOutputStream(FileName, true);
            FH.write(B64Sig.getValue());
            FH.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error writing to PDF file: " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Signature of '" +SignerName+ "' appended to '"+FileName+ "'.");
    }

    private static List<byte[]> ListUserCerts(String User, String Domain, String Pass) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Retrieving list of certificates for user: " + User);

        DssSignResult result;
        try {
            //initiate connection to COSign SAPI service
            DSS service = new DSS();
            DSSSoap port = service.getDSSSoap12();

            SignRequest request = new SignRequest();

            RequestBaseType.OptionalInputs optInputs = new RequestBaseType.OptionalInputs();

            // SET SIGNATURE TYPE (create field + sign)
            optInputs.setSignatureType("http://arx.com/SAPIWS/DSS/1.0/enum-certificates");

            // SET USERNAME / PASSWORD
            RequestBaseType.OptionalInputs.ClaimedIdentity cosignUser = new RequestBaseType.OptionalInputs.ClaimedIdentity();
            NameIdentifierType userName = new NameIdentifierType();
            userName.setValue(User);
            userName.setNameQualifier(Domain);
            cosignUser.setName(userName);

            CoSignAuthDataType userPass = new CoSignAuthDataType();
            userPass.setLogonPassword(Pass);
            cosignUser.setSupportingInfo(userPass);
            optInputs.setClaimedIdentity(cosignUser);

            // SET FLAGS
            optInputs.setFlags(Long.valueOf(0));

            // ALL DONE, MAKE A CALL:
            request.setOptionalInputs(optInputs);
            request.setInputDocuments(null);
            result = port.dssSign(request);

            // CHECK RESULT:
            ResponseBaseType.Result rc = result.getResult();

            String errmsg = "" + rc.getResultMajor();
            if (errmsg.compareTo("urn:oasis:names:tc:dss:1.0:resultmajor:Success") == 0) {
                return result.getOptionalOutputs().getAvailableCertificate();
            }
            else {
                throw new Exception(rc.getResultMessage().toString());
            }
        }
        catch (java.rmi.RemoteException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    private static void SignDOCXExistField(String FileName, String FieldNameToSign, String SignerName, String SignerPassword) throws MalformedURLException
    {
        System.out.println("Trying to sign '" +FileName+ "' by '"+SignerName+ "' with password '"+SignerPassword+ "' ...");

        byte[] fileBytes = getPDFBytes(FileName);
        Base64Data corePDFBytes = new Base64Data();
        corePDFBytes.setValue(fileBytes);
        corePDFBytes.setMimeType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
        DocumentType myDoc = new DocumentType();
        myDoc.setBase64Data(corePDFBytes);

        // set signer - USERNAME/DOMAIN
        NameIdentifierType cosignUserProps = new NameIdentifierType();
        cosignUserProps.setValue(SignerName);    //User Name, try "John Miller"
        cosignUserProps.setNameQualifier(" ");      //Domain (relevant for Active Directory environment only)

        // set signer - PASSWORD
        CoSignAuthDataType cosignPassword = new CoSignAuthDataType();
        cosignPassword.setLogonPassword(SignerPassword);    //User Password, try "12345678"

        // set signer - USERNAME+PASSWORD
        RequestBaseType.OptionalInputs.ClaimedIdentity cosignUser = new RequestBaseType.OptionalInputs.ClaimedIdentity();
        cosignUser.setName(cosignUserProps);
        cosignUser.setSupportingInfo(cosignPassword);

        //initiate request components
        RequestBaseType.InputDocuments inputs = new RequestBaseType.InputDocuments();
        inputs.getDocumentHashOrOtherOrDocument().add(myDoc);       

        RequestBaseType.OptionalInputs optInputs = new RequestBaseType.OptionalInputs();
        optInputs.setSignatureType("http://arx.com/SAPIWS/DSS/1.0/signature-field-sign");
        optInputs.setClaimedIdentity(cosignUser);
        //optInputs.setSignatureFieldName(FieldNameToSign);

        //initiate connection to COSign SAPI service
        DSS service = new DSS(new URL("https://prime.cosigntrial.com:8080/sapiws/dss.asmx"));
        DSSSoap port = service.getDSSSoap12();

        //initiate request
        SignRequest request = new SignRequest();
        request.setOptionalInputs(optInputs);
        request.setInputDocuments(inputs);

        //make the call
        DssSignResult result = port.dssSign(request);

        //CHECK RESULT:
        ResponseBaseType.Result rc = result.getResult();
        String errmsg = "" + rc.getResultMajor();
        if (errmsg.compareTo("urn:oasis:names:tc:dss:1.0:resultmajor:Success") != 0) {
            System.out.println("Cannot sign '"+FileName+"' got: "+rc.getResultMessage().getValue());
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Trying to append signature to '" +FileName+ "' ('"+SignerName+ "') ...");

        // IF OK Get the signature:
        ResponseBaseType.OptionalOutputs.DocumentWithSignature signedFile = result.getOptionalOutputs().getDocumentWithSignature();
        byte[] newFileBytes = signedFile.getDocument().getBase64Data().getValue();

        try
        {
            FileOutputStream FH = new FileOutputStream(FileName);
            FH.write(newFileBytes);
            FH.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error writing to PDF file: " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("The document was successfully signed");
    }
}
```